# Logoff all users from server except of one

Tags: windows, powershell

I have this script to logoff all disconnected users from a server. The problem is that one of them needs to be listed disconnected and can't log it off.

The issue is that the script works with a string result from `query user` and I don't know how to isolate one of the users.

```
$server = "localhost";

# Get all RDP sessions
$sessions = query user /server:$server | select -Skip 1;

# Loop through each session/line returned
foreach ($line in $sessions) {
    $line = -split $line;

    # Check for missing SessionName field/column
    if ($line.length -eq 8) {
        # Get current session state (column 4)
        $state = $line[3];

        # Get Session ID (column 3) and current idle time (column 5)
        $sessionid = $line[2];
        $idletime = $line[4];
    } else {
        # Get current session state (column 3)
        $state = $line[2];

        # Get Session ID (column 2) and current idle time (column 4)
        $sessionid = $line[1];
        $idletime = $line[3];
    }

    # If the session state is Disconnected
    if ($state -eq "Disc") {
        # Check if idle for more than 1 day (has a '+') and log off
        if ($idletime -like "*+*") {
            logoff $sessionid /server:$server /v
        } elseif ($idletime -like "*:*") {
            logoff $sessionid /server:$server /v
        }
    }
}
```

This is a example result from `query user`. The user I want to leave as disconnected is p.vbr.1

```
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 a2270725-3                               13  Disc      2+00:17  7/2/2019 1:50 PM
 a2232655-3                               14  Disc      4+09:54  7/1/2019 2:10 AM
 a2129521-3                               30  Disc      2+04:50  7/1/2019 4:52 AM
 a16991754-3                              49  Disc        22:51  7/1/2019 5:44 AM
 p.vbr.1                                  58  Disc      4+20:19  6/25/2019 11:20 AM
 a16990384-3                              59  Disc         1:43  6/27/2019 10:20 AM
 a2169135-3                               68  Disc      3+00:50  7/2/2019 11:13 AM
 a2289685-3                               79  Disc         6:40  7/2/2019 9:04 PM
>a2310806-3            rdp-tcp#93         85  Active          .  7/1/2019 9:05 AM
 a16991667-3                              98  Disc      3+00:31  6/26/2019 6:35 AM
 a2064837-3                              107  Disc         8:32  7/3/2019 12:47 AM
 a2282463-3                              108  Disc      2+01:51  7/3/2019 8:55 AM
 a2292833-3                              116  Disc      1+21:30  7/3/2019 2:06 PM
 a18005447-3                             126  Disc      8+20:09  6/26/2019 2:48 PM
 a2185113-3                              135  Disc         9:19  6/26/2019 9:14 PM
 a2067993-3                              139  Disc      1+03:58  7/4/2019 8:08 AM
 a2101008-3                              140  Disc         5:10  7/3/2019 10:00 PM
 a2256517-3                              141  Disc      1+03:32  7/4/2019 8:32 AM
 a2340150-3                              142  Disc        12:35  7/4/2019 9:53 PM
 a2076309-3                              143  Disc         3:37  7/5/2019 3:37 AM
```

Comment: *"The problem is that one of them needs to be listed disconnected and can't log it off."* What does that mean? Please show sample output from `query user` and indicate which of the sessions you want logged off, and which you want to remain logged on.

Comment: I have added the results, thank you.

Comment: Is the user running some ancient piece of software that requires a user account to execute it? Just wondering the business need behind the use case

Comment: What are your criteria to distinguish that name from other names? Do you want only the user with that particular name to remain logged in? Or do you want to log out all users whose name matches the pattern `^a\d+-\d$`? Also, you can specify a session limit for users, after which they're automatically logged out. That might be a more reliable approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the username would end up in `$line[0]`, so just add this at the beginning of your loop:

```
if ($line[0] -eq "p.vbr.1") {continue;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this general [`ConvertFrom-SourceTable`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertFrom-SourceTable) cmdlet.
It creates common objects from a fixed-width table, which makes your script much easier to read and manage:

```
$Query = query user /server:$server
$Sessions = ConvertFrom-SourceTable -Literal $Query

$Sessions | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Disc'} | ForEach-Object {
    If ($_.UserName -eq "p.vbr.1") {Continue}
    If ($_.'Idle Time' -like "*+*") {
        logoff $_.Id /server:$server /v
    } ElseIf ($_.'Idle Time' -like "*:*") {
        logoff $_.Id /server:$server /v
    }
}
```